# How to transition entire vue.js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So all the examples I keep seeing for transitions are for showing divs, I'm trying to come up with a simple way to transition my entire vue.js components with a fade in.

I have included an example of my vue.js layout.  i'm sure there are tons of syntax errors - but this example is just to illustrate how i am organizing my app in vue.js

as you can see, I am programmatically creating css for each component, so I would prefer (if possible) not to have a  block sitting outside of my component.  I don't know if vue.js has some hook to allow transitioning entire components or if i have to write a solution from scratch in javascript.

```
    <div id="vue-main" :style=mainStyle>
      <stages :jobs=jobs></stages>
      <binaries :jobs=jobs></binaries>
    </div>


    <script>
    Vue.component('stages', {
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        props: ['jobs', 'report_links'],
        template: `
          <div emptyDiv>
          <h3> Stages </h3>
          <table :style="tableStyle">
            <tbody>
              <template v-for="item in jobs">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    [[ item ]]
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        `,
         computed: {
            overviewStyle() {
              return {
                'padding': '8px',
                 'width': '100%',
                 'display': 'table',
                 'border': '1px solid #C0C0C0'
          };
    Vue.component('overview', {
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        props: ['jobs', 'report_links'],
        template: `
        <div overview>
        <h3>Overview</h3>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Start Time</td>
            <tde>[[ jobs[0].start_time ]]</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Duration</td>
            <td>[[ jobs[0].duration ]]</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        `,

var v_root = new Vue({
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    el: '#vue-main',
    data: {
        job_execs: [],
        report_links: '{{ report_links }}',
    },
    computed: {
      mainStyle() {
        return {
            'padding-left': '15px',
            'padding-right': '15px',
            'padding-bottom': '15px',
            'padding-top': '4px',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'width': '100%'
        };
```

How can I fade in the stages component?

Comment: You would register each component in the router and in your `App.vue` markup surround the `<router-view/>` tag in a transition.

Comment: I'm not using a router because this is not a single page application - i thought router was only for single page app

Comment: Ahh, this should be helpful, then.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-component-transitions-in-vue

Comment: i'm not using vue cli either

Comment: without having Vue CLI you may need to roll it yourself in vanilla js